# Assigning icons to a ComboBox's List using dynamically-loaded external images

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, components

I'm trying to implement this for an instance of ComboBox specifically, which uses a List to display the dropdown menu full of items. Lists can have icons associated with them, as [described in the documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/controls/List.html#iconField):

```
var comboBox = addChild(new ComboBox());
comboBox.dataProvider = new DataProvider([{label:'item1',iconClass:IconClass1},{label:'item2',iconClass:IconClass2}]);
comboBox.dropdown.iconField = 'iconClass';
```

... assuming IconClass1 and IconClass2 are valid classnames of symbols in our library, this code works perfectly.

**Here's my question** - the contents of this ComboBox will be XML-driven, populated dynamically, and I'd really rather include that icon reference as a filename instead of a classname, so that when the whole thing is implemented, the icon can be changed in the XML without opening Flash and adding a new symbol to the library. Clients aren't generally good at that sort of thing.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to find a way to reference the container for the instance of that icon class - the ComboBox.dropdown is obviously keeping a reference to each list item somewhere, and if I can find it, I can load the icon images dynamically, then addChild them to the icon instance. See what I'm saying?

Is this possible? Is there another trickier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but I would assume you could just use a basic custom class, say ImageIconField, which you would instantiate with each image, pass in with data in DataProvider and set iconField.  Like so:

```
var customImageIcon:ImageIconField;
var dataProviderArr:Array = [];
for (var node:XML in xml_data.children()) {
    customImageIcon = new ImageIconField();
    customImageIcon.loadFromFile(node.@icon_path.toString());
    dataProviderArr.push({label:xml_data.@label.toString, iconClass:customImageIcon})
}
combobox.dropdown.iconField = 'iconClass';
combobox.dataProvider = new DataProvider(dataProviderArr);
```